# Find the real coefficients of $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {\sum_{i=0}^n q_if(x+ha_i)}{h^n} = f^{(n)}(x)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, limits, derivatives

For every $n \in \Bbb N$ and for every unique real numbers $a_0, a_1,...a_n$ find the real coefficients $q_0,q_1,...,q_n$ such that

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {\sum_{i=0}^n q_if(x+ha_i)}{h^n} = f^{(n)}(x).$$

- I know I should show my own attempt of a solution, but I really have no idea, any hint please?